# Functions work even when headers have not been included - Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio

I routinely notice while working in Visual C++ that some functions work even when their headers have not been included. For example, `tolower()` works even when `ctype.h` is not included.

This behaviour causes problems for me when I participate in online programming competitions, the program works fine and dandy when I run it on my computer but on submission, gives a `function not defined` error. Is there any way to stop this behaviour?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The declaration of your `tolower()` is in fact included. It could be so in one of the following ways:

- `<cctype>` or `<ctype.h>` is included in one of the headers (even standard headers) that you have included. The standard does not forbid standard headers to include other standard headers
- one of the headers you have included has the declaration of that funciton. For example, `<algorithm>` could have `int tolower(int);` somewhere in its code.

You cannot forbid this behavior. What you can do is learn where the function has to be defined/declared and never rely on inclusion of that header by other headers. You know where `tolower` is declared, so do include `<cctype>` every time you use this function.

Answer (score 0):

Possible explanations:

- You have your warning level turned right down.
- You're using precompiled headers that are including the right files.